# SQLite Cursor Not Looping Correctly - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Here is method:

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> getDays() {
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM debt;", null);

    nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    dayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String indName[] = new String[c.getCount()];
    String indDay[] = new String[c.getCount()];

    int d = 0, j = 0, u = 0;

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        indName[j++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("debt_name")); 
        indDay[d++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pay_day")); // line 384
    }   

    for (String name : indName) {
        if ((indDay[u] != "") || (indDay[u] != null)) {
            dayList.add(Integer.valueOf(indDay[u++]));

        }
    }
    c.close();

    return dayList;
}
```

I am getting an error at Line 384 that says:
"Couldn't read row 0, col -1.  Make sure cursor is initialized."

Line 384 is marked above.
Can you find anything that I am missing here?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project, then try again and see if the error points now to the correct line...

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM debt` remove `;`

Comment: I think your code is absolutely riht.

Comment: I rebuilt and it is pointing to line 384 actually.  I removed the ";", didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove ; from end of your Query : `SELECT * FROM debt`

call this line :

```
//optional
//"this"  is your DBHELPER class
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

replace (marked for block) by this

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
            indName[j++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("debt_name"));
            indDay[d++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pay_day"));

        }   ( Line 386!!! )

}
```

Comment: try to use : c.getColumnIndex(0) or c.getColumnIndex(1) or another int value. i think your problem is lack of correct column "pay_day"

Comment: You are absolutely correct and got me on the right track.  The pay_day is actually named pay_date.  very bad mistake, I know.  Thanks!

Comment: if answer is useful point it up and click on Tick to make it Green and mark as best answer. see you buddy ;)

Answer (score 0):

put c.moveToNext();

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        indName[j++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("debt_name")); 
        indDay[d++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pay_day")); // line 384

    enter code here// c.moveToNext();
    }
```